# Enabling change picture button when current picture is hovered

Tags: html, css

I have a image when hovered should show a small pencil icon to change upload new image. I am new to css, I have set the visibility of the icon to `hidden` by default. But when i change the visibility on hover to `visible`. It doesn;t show up.

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
     <img id = "personal_profile_pic" src = "https://x1.xingassets.com/assets/frontend_minified/img/users/nobody_m.original.jpg">
  <a href="#">
    <span id="upload_pic_icon">
          <label for="avatar" id="avatar_label">
               <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </label>                        
    </span>
  </a>
       <form id="change_pic_form">
            <input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar">                                
       </form>

  </img>
</div>
```

Here is my css

```
#upload_pic_icon{
    margin-left: 62%;
    margin-top: -25%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#personal_profile_pic:hover #upload_pic_icon{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

I don't understand how to go about this.

Comment: I think it is because if the element is hidden, you can't hover it (since it's not there)

Comment: If you want `#upload_pic_icon` to appear once you hover `#personal_profile_pic` use Javascript, for example jQuery: `$('#personal_profile_pic').hover(function () { $('#upload_pic_icon').show(); });`

Comment: But is there any other with css ?

Comment: @Naveen Kumar  where is the image of your pencil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `+` selector , it will select `#upload_pic_icon` that are placed immediately after `#personal_profile_pic`

```css
#upload_pic_icon{
  margin-left: 62%;
  margin-top: -25%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#personal_profile_pic:hover + #upload_pic_icon {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <img width="200" id="personal_profile_pic" src="https://x1.xingassets.com/assets/frontend_minified/img/users/nobody_m.original.jpg">
  <a href="#" id="upload_pic_icon">
    <span>
          <label for="avatar" id="avatar_label">
               <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </label>                        
    </span>
  </a>
  <form id="change_pic_form">
    <input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar">
  </form>
</div>
```

Or you can `wrap` `img` and `edit` in div and the set `hover` on `.wrap`, and use `display:none` instead.

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrap #upload_pic_icon {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
.wrap:hover #upload_pic_icon {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <div class=wrap>
    <img width="200" id="personal_profile_pic" src="https://x1.xingassets.com/assets/frontend_minified/img/users/nobody_m.original.jpg">
    <a href="#" id="upload_pic_icon">
      <label class="fa fa-pencil" for="avatar" id="avatar_label">
      </label>
    </a>
  </div>
  <form id="change_pic_form">
    <input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be wrapping html content inside an `<img>` tag, it's not syntatically correct.

Place all your content after the image tag, and trigger the css on hover using `+` selector. Use `opacity` instead of `visibility` as well for smoother transitions.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <img id="personal_profile_pic" src="https://x1.xingassets.com/assets/frontend_minified/img/users/nobody_m.original.jpg"/>
  <a href="#">
    <span id="upload_pic_icon">
      <label for="avatar" id="avatar_label">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </label>                        
    </span>
  </a>
  <form id="change_pic_form">
    <input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar">                                
  </form>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#upload_pic_icon {
    opacity: 0;
}

#personal_profile_pic:hover + #upload_pic_icon {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing opacity from a very small value which the img could be considered invisible to fully visible (1.0). But your logic is likely wrong as there is no sense to hover something previously invisible.

```
#upload_pic_icon{
    margin-left: 62%;
    margin-top: -25%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.000001;
}

#personal_profile_pic:hover #upload_pic_icon{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple Here is the Solution

https://jsfiddle.net/dineshkanivu/uddv4y9z/

HTML

```
<div class="MyImage">
  <div class="penLayer">
  <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/snipicons/500/pencil-128.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.MyImage{
background: url("http://gretchenrubin.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/big_small_.jpg");
 width: 350px;
height: 263px;
position:relative
}
.penLayer{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  display:none;

}
.penLayer img{width:60px;
height:60px;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:50%;
margin-top:-30px;
margin-left:-30px}
```